# Refresh PHP Page passing some data

Tags: php

I have a long operation which I wish to break into chunks, giving some indication of progress - maybe just a simple message `processed X records in Y seconds`, reloading the same page after ever Z records.

I tried setting the number or records processed in `$_POST['num_Processed']` and refresh the page with `header("Refresh:0");`, but on page reload `$_POST` is empty.

How can I pass a single integer on reload, so that the script knows where to resume its operation?

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP sessions for your variable.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica No, first go to [the official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) with [its examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) before using 3rd party websites.